# Pass a laravel controller model to a react component

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

first of all, I am very sorry if this has already been answered. This is a question I've been breaking my head on, and can't seem to figure out any proper solution.

What I am trying to do is retrieve data from my database making use of a Laravel controller, and send this data to my React component.

So for example, I have a table filled with movies. In my controller, I retrieve all these movies using:

```
public function getMovies()
    {
        return Movie::select('id', 'name', 'description', 'image')->get();
    }
```

Then, I want to send this list of movies to my React component, where I want to go over a foreach to display all of them. How does one do this?
My apologies for this question. I am just starting to learn how to work with React to work on a project.

Comment: Got a solution yet? if you did, kindly post it as an answer and mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**First just change :**

```
public function getMovies()
    {
        return Movie::select('id', 'name', 'description', 'image')->get();
    }
```

**To :**

```
public function getMovies()
            {
                $movies = Movie::all();
                
                return ('yourview', compact(['movies']));
            }
```

Then, In your blade view just use

```
@foreach ($movies as $movie)
    <p>{{ $movies->name }}</p>
    <p>{{ $movies->description }}</p>
    <p>{{ $movies->image }}</p>
@endforeach
```